# Cannot Insert it into in my table for Special characters when ANSI_WARNINGS is Off even with nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, insert, string

I want to insert a data row into my table as name: **DSKWOR00** , but I get this error :

> String or binary data would be truncated.

so I turned ANSI_WARNINGS OFF and it inserted the row but the result **wasn't that my values**

here is my T-SQL :

**1**- Create My Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DSKWOR00](   [DSW_ID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,    [DSW_YY] [float] NOT NULL,    [DSW_MM] [float] NOT NULL,    [DSW_LISTNO] [nvarchar](12) NULL,    [DSW_ID1] [nvarchar](8) NULL,    [DSW_FNAME] [nvarchar](60) NULL,    [DSW_LNAME] [nvarchar](60) NULL,    [DSW_DNAME] [nvarchar](60) NULL,    [DSW_IDNO] [nvarchar](15) NULL,    [DSW_IDPLC] [nvarchar](30) NULL,    [DSW_IDATE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,    [DSW_BDATE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,    [DSW_SEX] [nvarchar](3) NULL,    [DSW_NAT] [nvarchar](10) NULL,    [DSW_OCP] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    [DSW_SDATE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,    [DSW_EDATE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,    [DSW_DD] [float] NULL,    [DSW_ROOZ] [float] NULL,    [DSW_MAH] [float] NULL,    [DSW_MAZ] [float] NULL,    [DSW_MASH] [float] NULL,    [DSW_TOTL] [float] NULL,    [DSW_BIME] [float] NULL,    [DSW_PRATE] [float] NULL,    [DSW_JOB] [nvarchar](6) NULL,    [PER_NATCOD] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_DSKWOR00] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(    [DSW_YY] ASC,    [DSW_MM] ASC,    [PER_NATCOD] Asc ) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**2**- Insert Into a row in My Table :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DSKWOR00
(DSW_ID,DSW_YY,DSW_MM,DSW_LISTNO,DSW_ID1,DSW_FNAME,DSW_LNAME,DSW_DNAME,DSW_IDNO,DSW_IDPLC,DSW_IDATE,DSW_BDATE,DSW_SEX,DSW_NAT,DSW_OCP,DSW_SDATE,DSW_EDATE,DSW_DD,DSW_ROOZ,DSW_MAH,DSW_MAZ,DSW_MASH,DSW_TOTL,DSW_BIME,DSW_PRATE,DSW_JOB,PER_NATCOD) 
VALUES 
('6773790024',1401,1,1,'80079349','¤ç¬ üóä','ö‘þõþîž','‘®¤þóä','1011','¢¥þ','0','¢¤õ','ü÷¤þ',' ñõ‘ä ¤þ¢õ',0,0,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',0,'OZ0509','4430928460')
```

**3**-The error if I insert with ANSI_WARNINGS ON :

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 3
String or binary data would be truncated.
--Note: My insert is correct I don't know why I'm seeing this error
```

**4**-So for fixing error I did this :

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

INSERT INTO dbo.DSKWOR00
(DSW_ID,DSW_YY,DSW_MM,DSW_LISTNO,DSW_ID1,DSW_FNAME,DSW_LNAME,DSW_DNAME,DSW_IDNO,DSW_IDPLC,DSW_IDATE,DSW_BDATE,DSW_SEX,DSW_NAT,DSW_OCP,DSW_SDATE,DSW_EDATE,DSW_DD,DSW_ROOZ,DSW_MAH,DSW_MAZ,DSW_MASH,DSW_TOTL,DSW_BIME,DSW_PRATE,DSW_JOB,PER_NATCOD) 
VALUES 
('6773790024',1401,1,1,'80079349','¤ç¬ üóä','ö‘þõþîž','‘®¤þóä','1011','¢¥þ','0','¢¤õ','ü÷¤þ',' ñõ‘ä ¤þ¢õ',0,0,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',0,'OZ0509','4430928460')

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

**5**- **Finally** My row will insert but it's not value I have inserted into the table !

```
---- My Values in Inser :  ('6773790034',1401,1,1,'80069349','¤ç¬ üóä','ö‘þõþîž','‘®¤þóä','1011','¢¥þ','0','¢¤õ','ü÷¤þ',' ñõ‘ä ¤þ¢õ',0,0,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',0,'OZ0509','4430928444')
---- What did Insert :       6773790034  1401 1 1  80069349   ¤ç¬? ü??     ?‘???î?   ‘®¤???    1011  ¢¥?    0  ¢¤?    ü÷?           ??‘? ¤?¢?  0 0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  OZ0509   4430928444
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the table structure for the [DSKWOR00] table. I think you'll find that the length of one or more fields is NOT big enough to hold the data you are trying to insert.
I suspect DSW_SEX

Comment: I think you're correct, because OP defined that column as `NVARCHAR(3)` but is trying to insert these 4 characters into it: `ü÷¤þ`.

Comment: thanks , I Fixed  DSW_SEX and used N'' it solved, How you find out to suspect DSW_SEX ?